# Getting Error when running install command

Tags: angular, npm-install, webpack-2

Not able to understand why am i getting this Error, i tried running the command as Administrator as well.

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--color=always"
npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path C:\csf_workflow\Projects\DataCentralUI\Main\DataCentral\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-48\binding.node
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall unlink

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\XXXXXXXXXXXXX\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-48\binding.node'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-48\binding.node'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\\node_modules\\node-sass\\vendor\\win32-x64-48\\binding.node',
npm ERR!   parent: 'datacentralui' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: I use the git bash shell and it normally works.  The other option is to right click on your Command icon and run that as Administrator, then try the installation.

Comment: I tried running as administrator, same Error

Comment: Have you tried clearing the NPM cache?

Comment: Have you tried running "npm rebuild node-sass"? And out of curiosity are you using Yarn? https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1804

Answer (score 0):

First, try:

```
npm cache clean
```

If that doesn’t fix things, it may be that the clean wasn't completely successful and there are still remnants. Take a look in %APPDATA%\npm-cache, or if you’re using PowerShell, $env:APPDATA\npm-cache. Manually remove everything in that directory, and try again.

Reference:

http://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/matt-harrington/2012/02/23/how-to-fix-node-js-npm-permission-problems/)